# Install PIP dependencies using python (using OS or Subprocess for executing CLI) and show progress in progress bar in tkinter

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, subprocess, homebrew

I want to install Node and some pip dependencies using brew and pip in python subprocess(CLI) and also show the status or percent of the download using the tkinter progress bar so the user can see the progress.

Is there any way I can do so?

For Ex:

```
    Subprocess.call("brew install node")
    Subprocess.call("pip install tensorflow")
    Subprocess.call("pip install pytorch")
    Subprocess.call("pip install django")
```

I want to show the progress of these calls in the progress bar

Comment: Using the `subprocess` will create a new process. Communicating with the other process can be very very hard. Why don't you use a thread from the `threading` library?

Comment: sorry maybe my question was not accurate to what I wanted to ask. still Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import time


progress = 0


def t_create_progress_bar():
    # Don't use a `tk.Toplevel` here
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.resizable(False, False)
    progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient="horizontal", length=400)
    progress_bar.pack()

    progress_bar.after(1, t_loop_progress_bar, progress_bar)

    root.mainloop()

def t_loop_progress_bar(progress_bar):
    progress_bar["value"] = progress
    # Update it again in 100ms
    progress_bar.after(100, t_loop_progress_bar, progress_bar)



# Start the new thread
thread = Thread(target=t_create_progress_bar, daemon=True)
thread.start()

progress = 0 # 0% done
Subprocess.call("brew install node")
progress = 25 # 25% done
Subprocess.call("pip install tensorflow")
progress = 50 # 50% done
Subprocess.call("pip install pytorch")
progress = 75 # 75% done
Subprocess.call("pip install django")
```

It implements a progress bar that is inside the new thread. `tkinter` isn't going to crash as long as we don't use it inside the main thread. That is why I have a global variable `progress` that is incremented in the main thread and the progress bar is updated in the new thread. The new thread is updated every 100ms using a `.after` loop.

Note that all of the variables that start with `t_` are only supposed to be accessed by the new thread and not the main thread.

**Edit:** The variable `progress` is out of 100