# tkinter progressbar not updating in time

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

I have made a script that calles certain functions. After every function I want to update my progress bar. This is my code of the progressbar:

```
class loading(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        s = ttk.Style()
        s.theme_use('clam')
        s.configure("red.Horizontal.TProgressbar", foreground='red', background='red')

        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self, style="red.Horizontal.TProgressbar", orient='horizontal',
                                   length=101, mode='determinate')
        self.progress.pack(pady=10)

    def updateprogress(self):
        self.progress.step(20)
        return
```

But when I try to call update progress after my script functions, it doesnt update untill the very end. So after all my functions are finished, the progress bar goes from 0 to 100 instead of with steps.

```
        loading.updateprogress()
        script.install_requerement()
        loading.updateprogress()
        script.clone_vuestore_front()
        loading.updateprogress()
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT:
I tried to use threads in my code. I will post the whole script this time:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import os
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import time


class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.wm_geometry('700x400')
        self.title('Install and integrate Vue Storefront')
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(first_page)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()
        return self._frame



class loading(tk.Frame):
    number=10
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

    def t_create_progress_bar(self):
        progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal", length=400)
        progress_bar.pack()

        progress_bar.after(1, self.t_loop_progress_bar, progress_bar)

        self.mainloop()

    def t_loop_progress_bar(self, progress_bar):
        progress_bar["value"] = self.number
        # Update it again in 100ms
        progress_bar.after(100, self.t_loop_progress_bar, progress_bar)


class first_page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        t = tk.Message(self, width=500,
                       text='first page')
        t.pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='Accept', command=lambda: \
            self.AcceptClick(master)).pack(side=tk.RIGHT,
                                           padx=5, pady=5)

    def AcceptClick(self, master):
        loadingclass =  master.switch_frame(loading)
        thread = Thread(target=loadingclass.t_create_progress_bar(), daemon=True)
        thread.start()

        loadingclass.number = 0  # 0% done
        subprocess.run('sudo apt-get update', shell=True)
        loadingclass.number = 25  # 25% done
        subprocess.run('apt install nodejs', shell=True)
        loadingclass.number = 50  # 50% done
        subprocess.run('sudo apt-get update', shell=True)
        loadingclass.number = 75  # 75% done


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()
```

The frame does switch and I see the progress bar. But now the script runs the subproccesses after i close the window instead I want to run a function, then update the progress bar.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Why do you have `progress` as a global variable? That isn't how you are supposed to use classes in python.

Comment: That whole global and staticmethod doesn't make any sense

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67004527/11106801).

Comment: I want to be able to call updateprogress() from anywhere. Thats why its a staticmethod. How do you suggest I should do it?

Comment: @amjada I suggest that you look at an OOP tutorial. You can change `progress = ttk.Progressbar(...)` to `self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(...)`, `progress.pack(...)` to `self.progress.pack(...)`, remove the `@staticmethod`, change `def updateprogress()` to `def updateprogress(self)`, `progress.step(30)` to `self.progress.step(30)`.

Comment: @TheLizzard I looked at the link you gave me. That worked perfectly fine but i want to use frames. I updated the code but I still can't update the progressbar after I ran my subprocess.

Answer (score 1):

As @TheLizzard suggested, try to change all local variables to static self vars. Also try to call `root.update()` when you update progress bar value (after `self.progressbar.step(...)`). Because `root.mainloop()`, as far as I know, is sync, that's why if you call it after your sync code, progressbar is updated only after this, and if you call it before - It'll just stop the code below.

Comment: If the process running is long enough it will still hang the window.

Comment: @TheLizzard, first of all, the author of the question haven't told any timings of the script, and secondly, if you do not call root.mainloop, tk won't update the frames, afaik

Comment: That is why you should run the GUI in another thread. Look at the comments (on the question). I linked something very similar which runs the GUI in another thread and can execute any process without making the window unresponsive.

Comment: @TheLizzard, I do not like the tk at all, so I use flaskwebgui or PyQt in my projects. So, when I used it long time ago, I used threading to separate my code and tk updates, and it worked fine

Comment: Threading and tkinter isn't a good idea. Tkinter can sometimes crash.

Comment: I have posted my whole script. If that helps?